# Unable to use client certificate authentication in PowerShell 5.1

Tags: powershell, ssl, https, client-certificates

I'm trying to authenticate a PowerShell script to a webserver using a ssl certificate.

- PowerShell 5.1 test code :

```ps
$webDepotCertificate = [System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate2]::new("/full/path/to/cetificate.pfx")

[Net.ServicePointManager]::SecurityProtocol = [Net.SecurityProtocolType]::Tls12

$response = Invoke-WebRequest -Uri "https://www.server.domain/" -Certificate $webDepotCertificate -Verbose
Write-Host $response.StatusCode
```

- PowerShell error :

```
Invoke-WebRequest : The request was aborted: Could not create SSL/TLS secure channel
```

- Apache log on script request :

```
[ssl:info] [client <IP>:61520] AH01964: Connection to child 7 established (server www.server.domain:443)
[ssl:debug] ssl_engine_kernel.c(2317): [client <IP>:61520] AH02043: SSL virtual host for servername server.domain found
[core:debug] protocol.c(2257): [client <IP>:61520] AH03155: select protocol from , choices=h2,http/1.1 for server www.server.domain
[ssl:debug] ssl_engine_io.c(1370): (70014)End of file found: [client <IP>:61520] AH02007: SSL handshake interrupted by system [Hint: Stop button pressed in browser?!]
[ssl:info] [client <IP>:61520] AH01998: Connection closed to child 7 with abortive shutdown (server www.server.domain:443)
```

The .pfx file contains both client certificate and private key issued by my own CA-Authority

All works fine server side (tested with multiples web browsers)

All works fine with PowerShell >= 6

There is something I miss to use my client certificate in powershell 5.1 ?

Comment: Does the pfx contain the private key? If the pfx is password protected you need to pass that to the `X509Certificate2` constructor

Comment: Yes, the pfx contains the private key and isn't password protected (No passphrase on the key)

Comment: Powershell 5.1 uses a different HTTP implementation, most likely this is the source of your problem: https://get-powershellblog.blogspot.com/2017/11/powershell-core-web-cmdlets-in-depth.html#L07

Comment: Thanks @Robert I understand why the test works differently with PS5.1 and PS6.
But the "-Certificate" parameter exists in PS5.1, it have to exists a way to use it ?

Comment: Maybe worth checking: If Diffie-Hellman key exchange is involved during TLS 1.2 negotiation, ensure the client's minimum key bit-length (on systems where PowerShell 5.1 is installed) matches or is not larger than what the server expects (see `HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\SecurityProviders\SCHANNEL\KeyExchangeAlgorithms\Diffie-Hellman\ClientMinKeyBitLength`).

Comment: @leeharvey1 : Nothing under `HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\SecurityProviders\SCHANNEL\KeyExchangeAlgorithms`

Comment: This is the reason it doesn't work in older PS versions: https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/4544